# How can I change the App Name with Compose-Multiplatform in macOS?

Tags: macos, compose-multiplatform

[How can I change it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRCqZ.png)

The App Name that nears Apple's logo, I can't change it, it shows `MainKt` all the time.

I used Compose-Multiplatform create an app from here:https://kmp.jetbrains.com/?_gl=1*1dhqnoa*_ga*NDczNTQyMDA2LjE3MDk0Njc5NDk.*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTcwOTQ5NDg4OS40LjEuMTcwOTQ5NTE2MS41MS4wLjA.&_ga=2.153841144.1565303169.1709467949-473542006.1709467949

Here is my code:

```kotlin
fun main() = application {
    val state = rememberWindowState(
        size = DpSize(400.dp, 550.dp),
        position = WindowPosition(300.dp, 200.dp)
    )
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication, title = "Something I can change", resizable = false, state = state) {
        LoginScreen()
    }
}
```

I got this:
[It only change the window's title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/549Av.png)

I want to change the title that near the Apple's stupid logo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you package your application you can set the "iconFile". See: https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/tree/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution